# React Select defaultValue is set but doesn't appear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-select

I've tried even manually setting the default values like in the documentation but no dice. I'm not sure if it's a styling issue or what. So below I posted what I have along with a screenshot.

```
  <Select
        components={animatedComponents}
        getOptionLabel={convertToLabel}
        getOptionValue={option => option.resource_name}
        isMulti
        onChange={changeEvent}
        options={users}
        theme={theme => ({
          ...theme,
          borderRadius: 0
        })}
        defaultValue={(props.value || []).map(convertToValue)}
        value={(props.value || []).map(convertToValue)}
      />
```

`convertToValue` function

```
  const convertToValue = props => {
    return {
      label: `${props.name} ${props.family_name}`,
      value: props.resource_name
    };
  };
```

convertToLabel function

```
  const convertToLabel = props => {
    return `${props.name} ${props.family_name}`;
  };
```

`changeEvent` function

```
  const changeEvent = (selectedOption, i) => {
    let option = {
      name: "reviewers",
      value: selectedOption
    };
    update({ target: option });
  };
```

users & props objects

```
users: 
  [
    {
      resource_name: "facebook_user1",
      name: "Joe",
      family_name: "Dirt"
    },
    {
      resource_name: "facebook_user2",
      name: "Trident",
      family_name: "White"
    }
  ]

props:
  {
    field: "placeholder",
    fieldType: "placeholderType"
    value:[
            {
              resource_name: "facebook_user1",
              name: "Joe",
              family_name: "Dirt"
            },
            {
              resource_name: "facebook_user2",
              name: "Trident",
              family_name: "White"
            }
          ]
  }
```

What I see on my screen.

[image]

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing more of the code (How is Select defined? Is the value prop being passed correctly to whatever is rendering the Select component?), but I wonder if it has something to do with defining a `value` and a `defaultValue`. Usually defining a `value` is for controlled components, where the default will just be whatever `value` equals. `defaultValue` is usually for uncontrolled components, where you won't supply a value. ([Docs on uncontrolled components.](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html))

Comment: @hellojeffhall <Select /> is defined from the react select library. Oh yeah I put both to test if I was setting the default value correct. Okay so I tried just defining the defaultValue as the react select documentation says and still the same result :/

Comment: Can you console.log(props.value) so we can see what is getting passed into the <Select/> ?

Comment: props
  {
     field: "placeholder",
     fieldType: "placeholderType",
     value: 
                {
                       {
                          resource_name: "facebook_user1",
                          name: "Joe",
                           family_name: "Dirt"
                        },
                        {
                           resource_name: "facebook_user2",
                           name: "Trident",
                           family_name: "White"
                         }
                }
  }

Comment: @hellojeffhall, the formatting on comments is weird. Check out the edited props above in the main post

Comment: In your console.log, is value an array? It looks like it's just some objects floating without the `[` and `]`. Maybe a typo?

Comment: It is an array sorry thats a typo. Will fix now

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely difficult to tell exactly what your issue is, without seeing the actual JSX of your select render. Here are a few issues I see, looking at your question, and some hard guesses at what might be happening.

- You should show us the full JSX render of your Select implementation
- You never show us what your `defaultValue` prop looks like, but
  remember that `value` is expected to be equal to one of your
  `option`s, not just an `option` 'value'
- Your label and option getter
  methods signature should be `getOptionLabel = (option) => string` and
  `getOptionValue = (option) => string`. You've used `props`, which
  might conflict with parent scope, in your instance.
- You probably want
  your `convertToValue` method signature to line up with those as well.
- Your `onChange` event method signature doesn't line up with
  React-Select, and may be causing you pain. See my [answer to this
  recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63910174/react-select-dynamic-dropdown-with-async-options-loaded-as-user-is-typing) for help on this.