# react-select dynamic dropdown with async options loaded as user is typing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, api, react-select

I'm new to React and I'm trying to merge 2 different features. A dynamic form where you can add and/or remove inputs AND one with async react-select where you can start typing a word and options appear and get filtered based on an API source (based on connected user for example)

I'm almost done (I think) BUT :

When I start typing I correctly see my options...and options get filtered correctly BUT when I click on an item (to select this item) I get an error.

The error I got is `Cannot read property 'name' of undefined` but I don't understand it and I'm not sure it's the only problem I got. I have no clue how to get my choice to cprrectly get selected and correctly put into my array of objects (`inputFields`)

Here are the 2 different sources I try to mix (They both work perfectly put independantly)

React-Select Async dropdown : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-select-async-component?file=index.js
Dynamic form field : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgKH12s_95A

Thank you for helping me understand what's the problem !!!

Here is my code :

```
function AsyncDynamicForm(props) {
  const [inputFields, setInputFields] = useState([
    { firstName: '' },
  ]);
  const [inputValue, setValue] = useState("");


  const handleChangeInput = (index, event) => {
    const values = [...inputFields];
    values[index][event.target.name] = event.target.value;
    setInputFields(values);
  };

  const AddFields = () => {
    setInputFields([...inputFields, { firstName: '' }]);
  };

  const RemoveFields = (index) => {
    const values = [...inputFields];
    values.splice(index, 1);
    setInputFields(values);
  };


  const loadOptions = (inputValue) => {
    return fetch(
      `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Objects/?q=${inputValue}`
    ).then((res) => res.json());
  };
    

  const handleInputChange = (value) => {
    setValue(value)
  };
  
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("inputFields", inputFields); // Nothing for now
  };


  return (
    <div>
        <Container>
          <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            {inputFields.map((inputField, index) => (
              <div key={index}>
                <Form.Field inline>
                  <AsyncSelect
                    name="firstName"
                    value={inputField.firstName}
                    onChange={(event) => handleChangeInput(index, event)}
                    cacheOptions
                    defaultOptions
                    getOptionLabel={(e) => e.name.toString()}
                    getOptionValue={(e) => e.id}
                    loadOptions={loadOptions}
                    onInputChange={handleInputChange}
                  />
                </Form.Field>
                <Button.Group basic size="small">
                  <Button icon="add" onClick={() => AddFields()} />
                  <Button
                    icon="x"
                    onClick={() => RemoveFields(index)}
                  />
                </Button.Group>
              </div>
            ))}
          
            <Button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
              click
            </Button>
          </Form>
        </Container>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AsyncDynamicForm
```

Comment: BTW, I would change the title of your question to 'Why is the onChange event not being called in my async React-Select?'

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://react-select.com/props) is very helpful here. The `onChange` prop takes a method with a specific signature.

```js
const onChange = (option, {action}) => {
  /* The `option` value will be different, based on the Select type
   * and the action, being one of `option`, an array of `option`s
   * (in the instance of a multiselect), `null` (typical when clearing
   * an option), or `undefined`.
   * What you actually get will depend on the `action` the select passes,
   * being one of:
   * - 'select-option'
   * - 'deselect-option'
   * - 'remove-value'
   * - 'pop-value'
   * - 'set-value'
   * - 'clear'
   * - 'create-option'
   */
   // example uses the `useState` hook defined earlier
   switch (action) {
     case 'select-option',
     case 'remove-value',
     case 'clear':
       setColor(option);
       break;
     default:
       // I'm not worried about other actions right now
       break;
   }
};
```

Remember that React-Select treats `value` as the entire `option` object, not just the `option` value you define in `getOptionValue`. If you're looking at setting a true form 'value', you'll probably wrap Select in some way to handle that.

React-Select is incredibly powerful, and incredibly complex. The documentation is your friend here. I find it helpful to play around in CodeSandbox, when trying out features I don't fully understand yet.